# ssh connection using RSA key keep asking password

Tags: ssh, solaris, rsa

I'm trying to set-up SSH connections without password to many servers, using RSA key. It works well for most of them but one is giving me some trouble.

The most common issue I've found in the past is permissions problems on .ssh or authorized_keys on the remote host, but here they seem correct, like this:

```
drwx------  ~/.ssh
-rw-r--r--  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Here is output of ssh -v command to this server (I just changed hostname and IP):

```
Sun_SSH_1.1.3, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090704f
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myhost.mydomain.com [123.123.123.123] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /export/home/webdev1/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /export/home/webdev1/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /export/home/webdev1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.5, remote software version 1.2.31
debug1: match: 1.2.31 pat 1.2.1*,1.2.2*,1.2.3*
debug1: Local version string SSH-1.5-Sun_SSH_1.1.3
debug1: Waiting for server public key.
debug1: Received server public key (768 bits) and host key (1024 bits).
debug1: Host 'myhost.mydomain.com' is known and matches the RSA1 host key.
debug1: Found key in /export/home/webdev1/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: Encryption type: 3des
debug1: Sent encrypted session key.
debug1: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: Installing crc compensation attack detector.
debug1: Received encrypted confirmation.
debug1: Doing password authentication.
```

I suspect it could be due to the SSH version. Another server which works gives me the following output (remote protocol version 2.0 instead of 1.5):

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_1.1.3
debug1: match: Sun_SSH_1.1.3 pat Sun_SSH_1.1.*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_1.1.3
```

Any clue?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server may be configured to refuse public-key-based, password-less authentication. I do not know about Sun_SSH, but in OpenSSH (the most prevalent SSH implementation on Linux/*BSD systems) this is a matter of changing some settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (options `RSAAuthentication` for v1 protocol, `PubkeyAuthentication` for v2).

Comment: Thanks for this information. I don't have root access to investigate the configuration of Sun_SSH but that's certainly the problem. I'll try to get a sysadmin involved.

Comment: `/etc/ssh/ssd_config` should be `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (or perhaps `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`)

Answer (score 3):

```
chmod 744 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

works for me.

Comment: "644" is better ... no need for execution. And also, the .ssh dir itself must be secured by "700". But +1 for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your home directory(`/export/home/webdev1`) too has `700` permission.

Answer (score 1):

try just

`chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/`

Maybe the group/global read permission is causing an issue.

Comment: I tried it but that doesn't help. Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: this helped me, along with copying the correct id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files into ~/.ssh/ folder

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your user was locked on the unix box. If you usually login with your own account and then "be" the functional user, if that user has "password login" functionalities enabled but you are not using it, it may be locked (password expired for example).
Howerver, even if it is locket it will not prevent you from sudo it with the "be" command, but it will definitly prevent any ssh login even if the keys are trusted.

Comment: Ok thanks Olivier, unfortunately I don't have access to these machines anymore, so I can't verify if that was the case. But if it happens to me again I'll check this ;o)